# Unable to scroll the page on iPad after closing popup window

Tags: html, css, ipad, scroll

1. Main page with buttons and content which is have scroll to the page, click on one of the buttons on right side.
2. Full page cover or half page cover popup open.
3. After closing popup tried to scroll the page but unable to do it and content hiding behind / white page shows.
4. expecting screen 1 as its with scrolling.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a live example? share your code i mean

Comment: A bit critical project, hence unable to add the code. Its contain animation for slick and flip part. If i removed the animation its working fine.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this CSS:

```
body{
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Comment: is this issue is getting only in ipad or other devices too?

Comment: only for iPad and iPhone.